# Abort an ongoing file upload via JS File Upload API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, xmlhttprequest, laravel-livewire

I'm currently developing a small web application which utilizes Laravel Livewire's File Upload. I can remove the file once the temporary file is done being uploaded but since it handles up to 1GB of file, I rather have an option to cancel a file upload via its JS API.

I've looked for nearly everywhere for answers, but it seems Livewire itself does not support this kind of action (yet?). I've also tried intercepting the XHR of the upload via its `progress` callback but the `event` param only returns an instance of `ProgressEvent` which contains this:
[image]

I've tried playing with its `XMLHttpRequestUpload` but after some reading on its documentation, I found out that it does not have any abort methods. I've also tried dispatching an event using `dispatchEvent()` function but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611340/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Sadly it does not since Livewire's API does not provide a way to access the XHR instance. so I'm stuck on that kind of feature. I'm thinking of actually overwriting the XHR to dispatch an event [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042483/7619826) and store them on an array constant so I can access them when need be, but I really think this is a very bad idea and practice itself...